# Android Share text on Facebook doesnt work

Tags: android, facebook, android-sharing

I have implemented an application and I have a share button to share a text, it´s working properly for all the options but doesnt work when I try to share it on Facebook the screen is empty.. I don´t know why. Any idea how to fix it??

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:title="@string/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

or How Can I hide facebook option from my list?

Thanks!!

Comment: Facebook don't allow prefilling text

Comment: so do u know how can I hide this option from the list? @WizKid

Comment: Have you tried the example at https://blog.xamarin.com/android-support-library-v7-hello-actionbarcompat/ where they sent the intent to text/plain?

Comment: Nope.. I'm going to try tonight. Thanks! @WizKid